# Open Word Document Fullscreen

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, fullscreen

How do I open a word document in fullscreen mode? It is not opened in a form, it gets opened with the following code:

```
Private MSWord As New Word.Application
Private WordDoc As New Word.Document

Private Sub OpenWordFullScreen(ByVal ReportName As String)
    MSWord = New Word.Application

    WordDoc = MSWord.Documents.Open("C:\" & ReportName & ".doc")

    'Make MSWord visible 
    MSWord.WindowState = Word.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMaximize
    MSWord.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open word in fullscreen, you add the following code snippet:

```
WordDoc.ActiveWindow.View.FullScreen = True
```

So your code will look like this:

```
Private Sub OpenWordFullScreen(ByVal ReportName As String)
    MSWord = New Word.Application

    WordDoc = MSWord.Documents.Open("C:\" & ReportName & ".doc")

    'Make MSWord Visible
    MSWord.Visible = True
    WordDoc.ActiveWindow.View.FullScreen = True
End Sub
```